# What can I pass into local variables in Rails partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial called "_share_links" which is a set of buttons to let users share a post.

The text and summary content that will prepopulate these links will be different on different pages. So for example, on a page showing an event, I want to use the event's name in the pre-populated link. On a different page, though, I may want to use the post title in the link.

I tried accomplishing this with the code below but I get a "undefined local variable 'name'" error.

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/share_links", locals: { page: @event, name: @event.name, body: @event.description } %>
```

**_share_links.html.erb**

```
<ul class="share-links">
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<%=u name %>&url=<%= request.original_url %>" target="_blank"><%= embedded_svg "twitter.svg", class: "svg-icon twitter svg-circle" %></a></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best practice for achieving something like this and passing different object attributes into the partial?

Thanks

Comment: According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) is your code perfectly valid. Is the source code of this project open?

Comment: Thanks. It's not open unfortunately... though I can post any other relevant bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I pass into local variables in Rails partials?

Anything. Its just a local variable in the rendering context of the partial. Rails does not question what you use it for.

> What is the best practice?

Locals is such a generic tool that its hard to say that there is any best practice.

The main point of locals is that it lets you make partials into a functional construct. What this means is that your partial will take a certain input and deterministically create a html output. This makes them very robust and easy to test in isolation. So using locals in this sense can be seen as a best practice.

So lets start by removing the coupling to `request` and cleaning the messy string interpolation up:

```
<ul class="share-links">
  <li>
    <% share_uri = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?" + { url: url, text: text }.to_query %>
    <%= link_to share_uri, target: "_blank" do %>
      <%= embedded_svg "twitter.svg", class: "svg-icon twitter svg-circle" %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now we can call it by:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/share_links", text: @event.name, url: url_for(@event) %>
```

This would create share link for a particular event. If you wanted a generic button on the footer which would share the current page you would do:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/share_links", text: 'Something generic', url: request.original_url %>
```

Using the key `locals` is no longer required - Rails will pass any additional options to the partial anyways.

Another issue is where to organise your partials. I would argue that `views/layouts` should only contain you guessed it, layouts.

Partials that do not belong to a certain resource are commonly placed in a folder called `views/shared`.

Comment: All though as a side comment this is a prime candidate for a helper method which are even easier to test.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a helpful answer. It's working now. I'm still not sure why my original code wasn't working, but the clean-up you recommended has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct way to do this is to [pass an object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-The+-3Aas+and+-3Aobject+options) to the partial, especially powerful if you have the same attributes for each model:

```
<%= render "layouts/share_links", object: @event, as: :obj %>
```

Then in your partial, you can use:

```
<ul class="share-links">
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<%=u obj.name %>&url=<%= request.original_url %>" target="_blank"><%= embedded_svg "twitter.svg", class: "svg-icon twitter svg-circle" %></a></li>
</ul>
```

This would entirely depend on whether you have similar attributes for your objects, though.

Comment: Thanks for this. I considered this method, but decided against it as the attributes will be different for different models.